# How do I find a value in a specific range based on a criteria?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the "km" value which applies to F2 in the range of D2 to E2 in column A.

I am NOT able to switch column A and B so the "gradient" is to the left of the "km".

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question doesn't look clear to me. From the description I cannot understand how do you want the value at column G to be calculated.

Comment: FILTER will give you a range of matching km for the gradient. If you add the min and max as additional criteria the km should become unique

Comment: Your gradiente got duplicates. So for gradiente -10 which would be the correct km? 3000 or 13000?

Comment: In this case the gradient I am trying to find must be between 4000 km(as per D2) and 20000 km (as per E2). 

If there is gradient duplicates in this range it doesnt matter which km it returns, as long as it is within the range. (So in this case it should return 13000).

Answer (score 1):

In cell G2:

- If you want the first match:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A28,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A28>=D2)*(A2:A28<=E2)*(B2:B28=F2),),0)),"No Match")
  ```
- If you want the last match:

  ```
  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((A2:A28>=D2)*(A2:A28<=E2)*(B2:B28=F2)),A2:A28),"No Match")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may use arrays to get the values:

[image]

Notice my formula gets the MAX KM in case there are more than 1 match, but always inside the range delimited by D2 and E2. You can change MAX to MIN,SUM, AVERAGE or whatever you need.

Also, please notice that depending on your Excel version you may need to enter the formula as an array formula so if you got and old version, introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=MAX(IF(B2:B28=F2;IF(A2:A28<=E2;IF(A2:A28>=D2;A2:A28))))
```

Actually, you can combine this with an aditional IF to check if there is any match first or not with COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B28;F2;A2:A28;">="&D2;A2:A28;"<="&E2)=0;"No match";MAX(IF(B2:B28=F2;IF(A2:A28<=E2;IF(A2:A28>=D2;A2:A28)))))
```

Comment: It works! Thanks man! So simple, yet so effective. Have an awesome day.